# How to get the type word inside the input field once after pressing the Comma key and not after pressing space bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've a input field and I want the typed word to appear once after pressing the Comma key and not after pressing the space-bar. Currently I have is after pressing the space-bar.
Thus how do I do it when I press only the Comma key.

Hope you understood my question.

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<input type="text" id="txtNames" placeholder="Type name here"/>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.tagsDiv
{
background-color:rgb(165, 215, 175);
color:black;
display: inline-block;
padding:5px;
height:30px;
margin:10px;
border-radius:5px;
}

.innerBody{
display:inline-block;
padding: 5px;
}
.close{
margin-left:-5px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:-7px;
text-decoration: none !important;
}
#wrapper{
width:400px;
min-height:200px;
border:black 2px solid;
}
#txtNames{
border:none;
outline:none;
padding:15px;
}
```

### JS

```
function createTag(vals)
{
var html='<div class="tagsDiv">'
         +'<div class="innerBody">'+vals.trim()+'</div>'
         +'<a href="#" class="close">x</button></div>';
$(html).insertBefore('#txtNames');
$('#txtNames').val('')
}


$("#txtNames").on('keypress',function(e){
if(e.which===32)
{
    if($(this).val().trim()!=='')
    {
    setTimeout(function(){
        createTag($('#txtNames').val());   
    },0);
    }
}
});

$(document).on('click','.close',function(){
$(this).parents('.tagsDiv').remove();
});
```

Comment: JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7q9nogwt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keyCode` for the spacebar is 32.  The `keyCode` for a comma is 188.

Replace

```
if(e.which===32)
```

with

```
if(e.which===188)
```

in your `keypress` handler.

### Update

For your specific needs of preventing the comma from being displayed as well as allowing the `enter` key, try this:

```
$("#txtNames").on('keydown', function (e) {
    // Grab the textbox value
    var value = $(this).val();

    // Check for ENTER or COMMA
    if (e.which === 13 || e.which === 188) {
        if(value) {
            createTag(value);   
        }

        // Cancel the event, preventing the ',' from 
        // appearing in the input box
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Enter is 13.  You can find a nice list of keycodes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: But how do I hide the comma in my input type word? 
And How can I use both the Comma and Enter Key

Comment: When I press comma then the comma also getting inside the word.
For eg: If I type John and press comma then I get John,

So how do I hide this comma in this word?

Comment: The `keypress` event fires AFTER the comma has been inserted.  If you want to prevent the comma from being inserted, you have to either use the `keydown` event and call `e.preventDefault()` or you have to modify the value of the `input` inside the `keypress` handler

Comment: `keydown` also allows the comma to be printed. Perform `$('#txtNames').val().replace(',','');`

Comment: @Niddro that's what `e.preventDefault();` is for.  No need for the `replace`

Comment: @Mohamed try refreshing the page?

Comment: @Mohamed try playing around with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8x28nwm/).  Note that calling `e.preventDefault()` inside the `keydown` event STOPS the `keypress` event from being fired, preventing the comma from being inserted.

Comment: Can you do me a favor @AlexMcMillan